# Heap corruption because of tracking reference?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, heap-corruption

I'm facing managed heap corruption. Could the following function potentially cause the corruption?

```
void EE::config(PT::DId^%dId){
  dpId = gcnew PT::DId(String::Format("{0}new", dId->Name));
}
```

Comment: This is not an obvious source of heap corruption.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be because the new DId-object has a longer Name property and therefore might overwrite the following object in memory...